# Azure alternatives for hosting Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, azure, blazor

Hosting **Blazor WebAssembly** on **Azure** seems to be expensive, particularly with a SQL Server database. Can a Blazor WebAssembly website be hosted outside the big names in Cloud? (Azure, AWS and the others) Any suggestions? I do not need a high traffic performance solution, a host with an "average" capabilities (say a couple hundred users per day, some 20 pages website or so, connected to a backend relational database say with some 20 tables of few 100K rows at max) and a low budget would do.

I have Googled that some suggest to use a static hosting for hosting a Blazor WebAssembly website, and on Azure that should be free? (as much as I gathered), but does not include a SQL Server database. If the database is the problem, any suggestions for an alternative data storage tech/approach (even a no-sql database) which can lead for the website (including its data storage part) to be hosted for free or a low budget? No matter what configurations I tried in Azure price calculator, I ended up with 100s$ per month - at least.

I'm aware of the first year trial/free Azure services for learning/development etc. but looking to know can I provide a working/business website with Blazor including the database and hosting, on a low budget.

Help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You know the old sayings. No such thing as a free lunch. and you get what you pay for!  Having said that, I have a customer on Azure Blazor Server with a SQL DB, and it's about $15 a month.  Not sure what plans you are looking at.  Are you overspecing what you need?

Comment: Create a $5/month VM in Linode or DigitalOcean. Install MySQL and a Web server on it.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Very useful.

Comment: You can host it on Azure, but if you use SQL database, make sure you check their calculator pricing, for static website, then it is OK. If you are using SQL database, Azure will be expensive. If I can recommend, you may check Asphostportal, it is shared hosting, it is around $8/month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from I can see there are two different questions.

- Approaches to host a Blazor WASM App
- Options for SQL Database

**Approaches to host Blazor WASM**
There are quite a few options to host cheaply.

- **Azure Container Apps**: For 10 million requests per month with 100 concurrent requests will cost between **$3 and $6**. The costs essentially depends on the usage (CPU and Memory usage).
- **Static hosting on Azure Storage**: All you pay for is the storage and the transactions. A similar spec as above will cost between **$4 and $6**
- **App Service**: A shared linux App Service will cost **$14**

**Options for SQL Db**
This depends on what you need, the data storage and how often you are going to hit the db in the first place

- **Azure SQL**: A basic Service Tier, 5 DTU, 2 GB database will cost **$5 - $6** based on backups
- **Cosmos DB**: Serverless 1 million RU with 2 GB storage will be **$1**. And Cosmos DB supports SQL APIs as well.

**PS 1**: All the costs are in USD.
**PS 2**: The specs mentioned in here are listed in the following url. https://azure.com/e/8a014ac17828453f901a14ab91754f47

Comment: Thanks Ebbz for your answer.

Comment: What are the disadvantages of using Azure Container App? Talking about Blazor WA with asp.net core web api as host..

Comment: Azure Container Apps is a relatively new offering from Microsoft and if I remember correctly it is currently available only on two regions East US and West Europe.